# JPA Join Fetch of a concrete class

Tags: java, jpa

I am using JPA with HIbernate and I have the following data structure:

```
 public class House {
        @ID
        Long id;
        @OneToMany(mappedBy = "House")
        private final List<Animal> animalList = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Dog> getDog () { return animalList.stream()
                .filter(Dog.class::isInstance).map(Dog.class::cast)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        }

    public abstract class Animal {
        @ManyToOne
        private House house;

    }

    public class Dog extends Animal {
        String ball;
    }
```

And I would like to perform a JPAQuery like :

```
select h.address, d.ball from House h join fetch h.animalList d where h.id = :id
```

As you may have noticed h.animalList is returning me objects of type Animal. Therefore d.ball is not allowed. However, I know that they are Dogs. 
I am asking:
1. Whether there is a way to force the conversion in the query without having to change the data structure. 
2. If there is a better design solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In JPA 2.1, you have `where TREAT (animal AS Dog) d`